# Two times the same variable declaration in the code to parse

Tags: antlr4

My problem is that the language I'm parsing needs to declare the same variable in two parts of the code. This is what I mean:

```
forward declaration
 type variable_name 
 end type
end forward declaration

type variable_name
end type
```

The grammar get both and the tree is fine, but I can't avoid the "mismatched input" anyway.

What is the way to deal with this kind of repeatible structures? Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem didn't come from the duplication, it came because i have no delimiter for each sentence and i was handling it wrong :-( sorry